# If $X$ and $Y$ are fundamental matrices then exists $C$ invertible such that $Y=XC$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

If $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are fundamental matrices then exists $C\in M_n$ invertible such thta $Y(t)=X(t)C$
Both for the homogeneous linear system $x'=A(t)x$.

**attempt:** Since $X$ is fundamental, it spans the solution space i.e.,  $$X'(t)=A(t)X(t)$$ but doing the same for $Y$ I go nowhere on finding $C$ invertible. I now that since $X$ is fundamental there is $t_0$ such that $\det(X(t_0))\neq 0$, even more $\det(X(t))\neq 0$ for all $t$, but again go nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You determine $C=X(t_0)^{-1}Y(t_0)$ at one point and then use that both solve the same linear differential equation to confirm that this relation holds with a constant $C$, that is, outright define $Y(t)=X(t)C$ and conclude from
$$
X'=AX\\
(XC)'=X'C=AXC\\
Y'=AY
$$
that $Y$ is indeed a solution.